# table row order are not updatin in the database after ajax call in django

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am using jquery UI .sortable to sort my table rows by drag and drop. I have declare a field map_order in the model as an order update. so the thing is when I am making ajax call to update the model order field. it didn't update it. but when I console log the sort variable it will show the assigning of index to the pk of model.

I have tried to update the filed but it did,nt work

```
        HTML
     <tbody id="#layerTable">
                {% for layer in layers %} ​
                <tr data-pk="{{ layer.id }}" class="ui-state-default">      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="{{ layer.id }}" /></td>        

<td> <a href="{% url 'mapport.maps.layers.one' map.id layer.id %}">{{ layer.name }}</a> </td>       
    <td>{{ layer.heading }}</td>        
    <td>{{ layer.class_group }}</td>        
    <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical"></span> {{ layer.map_order }}</td>       
    <td>{{ layer.map_server }} </td>        
    <td> {% if layer.sql_schema %}{{ layer.sql_schema }}.{{ layer.sql_table }}{% endif %} </td>
                </tr>

    ​
JS
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tbody").sortable({
     update: function(event, ui) {
​
        sort = {};
        window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}";
        $("tbody").children().each(function(){
        sort[$(this).data('pk')] = $(this).index();
    });
​
        {#var csrftoken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();#}
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url "mapport.maps.layers.all" map.id %}sort/",
      type: "post",
      data:{sort,
       csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN,
      },
​
    });
     console.log(sort)
      },
    }).disableSelection();
  });
​
</script>

views
  @csrf_exempt
    def sort(self):
        for index, pk in enumerate(self.request.POST.getlist('layer[]')):
            layer = get_object_or_404(Layer, pk=pk)
            layer.map_order = index
            layer.save()
​
        return HttpResponse('')
```

I I have expected to update the field map_order.. but it didn't update. the index is assigning in browser to the id when I drag and drop rows

Comment: Please give sample output which you get in console.

Comment: it is giving the list of dict in this format {layer_id: index_No}..   every time I drag and drop it will reassigning the index successfully but not updating in layer.map_order in database

Comment: is it show in table something like 1,10,2,3,31

Comment: Yes sir.. Exactly.. It is showing the indexing of the row.. Like 0,1,2

Comment: Add your table output, this will help to understand how data display in table

Comment: {1243:1}, {1253:0},{1256:2}, {1257:4}

Comment: THis serial is ok. I want to see the table which you show in browser

Comment: You want to see the front end? Or the html? Html is in the code section above

Comment: Where you see table order is not correct

Comment: I have console.log the sort The thing is when i drag and drop row.. The index instantly change in the console.. But i refresh the browser the index come backwards.. The only thing is the index is not interacting with layer.map_order so that it can save